# Does "I took a swing at him" tell anything about whether I hit him or not?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

1)

I grabbed a bat and took a swing at him.

Does this tell anything about whether I hit him or not?

2)

Then I took another swing at him.

If I have just taken one swing at him with a bat, could I say the above or would I have to make it clear that it was the bat I used again and say something like...

Then I took another swing at him with the bat/Then I swung the bat at him again.

?

Comment: You could just say "I took a swing at him with a bat, and then I took another".

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is said about whether you hit him or not. To take a swing at someone or something (e.g. a ball in a game such as baseball) is to **attempt** to strike them or it, with a fist, weapon, bat, etc. The context or following words will clarify whether the swing **connected** (the objective was achieved). It is possible to say "He took a swing at me but I ducked".

> Definition of take a swing
>
> to try to hit something
>
> Some drunk took a swing at me. The batter took a swing at the first
>   pitch.

[Take a swing (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20a%20swing)